# How can do a bulk delete of users in Civi?

Tags: permissions

How can do a bulk delete of users in Civi?
We have too many user accounts in civi and would like to delete may of them and only keep the ones that we need.
Instead of looking up the accounts one at a time. I would like to select a group of records and delete them.

Thanks in advance
Edward

Comment: Hi Edward. Just trying to help clear up the terminology. Civi doesn't have 'user' accounts. Those are in your CMS, and it might help if you specify which you use.

Comment: peterdnz, Thanks for responding. Sorry for the confusion. I meant user account. That is users that can log in to civicrm with a user name and password. I did not mean contacts as not all contacts have user accounts.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a Drupal and not a CiviCRM question.  A good answer is posted [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38942/how-to-delete-blocked-users-in-bulk); an alternate approach is the [Bulk User Delete module](https://www.drupal.org/project/userdelete), but for your use case I think that might not be as easy as some of the answers under the first link.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean 'how do I bulk delete contacts', then you can do this via the Advanced Search (or Find Contacts). Find the contacts you want to delete, tick those records, then under Actions you will find Delete Permanently.

If you also want to delete the 'user accounts' then that will depend on the CMS. For example in Drupal, we tend to recommend deleting the Civi contact first, and then finding Drupal users who do not have a uf_match record, and deleting those. We found that making a Drupal View using Bulk Views Operations to facilitate this.

Comment: peterdnz, Thanks for responding. Sorry for the confusion. I meant user account. That is users that can log in to civicrm with a user name and password. I did not mean contacts as not all contacts have user accounts

Comment: We are currently using Drupal.

Comment: Is there a way to use Views Bulk Operations to delete the CMS record and then move the related Civi Record to trash - simultaneously? I built a Drupal view that is giving me the Drupal login/access data and other website info to make sure the contact isn't a contributor, and then linked Civi data into the view. I can determine now they are spam. Can the VBO hit the kill button for both?

Comment: Maybe a VBO to delete the user, and a Rules tacked on that says, if Drupal user deleted then trash civi contact - but i don't know if Rules can do that since presumably it doesn't have the information it needs before it is too late. May work if you were okay to set the User to Blocked, and then trigger a Rule to delete both User and Contact ie while you still have both entities in existence? But of course that kind of overrides what Blocked is for but hopefully thinking aloud might trigger some other thoughts from others. do feed back if you come up with something.

Comment: (above should have said, "then trigger a Rule based on USER SET TO BLOCKED to delete ...)